# Can you load a JSON object into a duckdb table with the Node.js API?

Tags: node.js, duckdb

The [duckdb Node.js API](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/nodejs/overview) can load data from a [JSON file](https://duckdb.org/docs/data/json/overview). However, I don't see a way to load data from a JSON object, similar to the way duckdb [Wasm ingestion](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/wasm/data_ingestion) works. Is there a way to do this without writing JSON to a file and then loading from the file?

Answer (score 0):

The NodeJS API reference for duckDB states that you can load data directly using the [prepare](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/nodejs/overview#prepared-statements) method or using the apache-arrow library ([Ref here](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/nodejs/overview#inserting-data-via-arrow)).

The below code (from the overview section of their docs) prepares a statement that you can the use to add a single entry to the table:

```
// conn is a connection to your database with a table 'tableName' in it
const stmt = con.prepare('INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (?)');

// Now you can run the statement with the value you want to insert into the database
stmt.run(valueToInsert);
```

It's worth noting the docs also say loading large numbers of values using INSERT is inadvisable, presumably because it's slow. It may therefore actually be faster to write to a json file and then read it using SELECT.